# Middle Term of List from Inputs

Tags: python

I need to take 3 numbers and print the max, min and middle term. Here's what I wrote:

```
new_list = []
for i in range(3):
    new_list.append(int(input("Enter a number: ")))

x = min(new_list)
y = max(new_list)
z = 


print("The max is %d, the middle is %d and the min is é %d." % (y, x , z))
```

But I don't know how to define z so it can be the middle term. Any help?

Comment: Sort by value, get the mid one

Answer (score 3):

Just sort them:

```
x, z, y = sorted(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it using list comprehension.

```
new_list = []
for i in range(3):
    new_list.append(int(input("Enter a number: ")))

x = min(new_list)
y = max(new_list)
z = [i for i in new_list if i!=x and i!=y][0]

print("The max is %d, the middle is %d and the min is é %d." % (y, z , x))
```